# Error accessing Rabbit MQ UI on macos installed via homebrew

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, macos-mojave, rabbitmq-management

I installed Rabbit MQ on my local machine running OS X via:

`brew install rabbitmq`

and I start and stop the server via:

`brew services start/stop rabbitmq`

I installed the plugin for the web UI via:

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

I expected to view the web UI in the browser at:

http://localhost:15672/

It does not load. The error reported is a 431 which means request header fields are too large.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/431

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in Chrome on OS X (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/410#issuecomment-307145632).

The web UI loads at http://0.0.0.0:15672/ but not localhost.

I also confirmed localhost worked on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I had a similar issue when running a docker image of Rabbit MQ on Windows. For me it worked by accessing http://127.0.0.1:15672 in Chrome (or worked directly in FF).